# Task "concurrent:server" not found

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to build a yeoman generator that uses the foundation-five gruntfile but the tasks are not found. Only the clean task is found.

```
Warning: Task "concurrent:server" not found. Use --force to continue
```

Related codes is [here](https://github.com/bauschan/generator-foundation-five/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js), how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into similar issues when trying to 'reuse' a gruntfile.js. You may need to install the relevant grunt packages from npm - packages that grunt is relying upon, but have not actually been installed in your project.  In this case, from your terminal, inside the project folder:

$ npm install grunt-concurrent

(https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-concurrent)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to apply the foundation 5 yeoman generator to my own. It took a little effort to figure out what files and other configurations were required. Apparently there is more to it than just trying to reuse a Gruntfile.js which does not surprise me since I am new to yeoman and grunt.

Here are some of the lines I added to my index.js

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// setup the test-framework property, Gruntfile template will need this
this.testFramework = options['test-framework'] || 'mocha';

// for hooks to resolve on mocha by default
options['test-framework'] = this.testFramework;

// resolved to mocha by default (could be switched to jasmine for instance)
this.hookFor('test-framework', { as: 'app' });

skipMessage: options['skip-install-message']

    var webappDir = 'src/main/webapp/html/';

      this.template('_Gruntfile.js', webappDir + 'Gruntfile.js');
      this.template('_package.json', webappDir + 'package.json');
      this.copy('bowerrc', webappDir + '.bowerrc');
      this.copy('_bower.json', webappDir + 'bower.json');
      this.copy('jshintrc', webappDir + '.jshintrc');
      this.copy('editorconfig', webappDir + '.editorconfig');
      this.mkdir(webappDir + 'uat');
      this.copy('_dalekjs-tests.js', webappDir + 'uat/dalekjs-tests.js');
      this.indexFile = this.readFileAsString(path.join(this.sourceRoot(), 'index.html'));
      this.indexFile = this.engine(this.indexFile, this);
      this.directory('app', webappDir + 'app', true);
      this.write(webappDir + 'app/index.html', this.indexFile);
```

Hopefully this is useful for someone coming along and trying to merge Foundation 5 yeoman generator code with their own generator.

Answer (score 0):

First install all necessary grunt modules from the same folder where you have Gruntfile.js:

```
npm install grunt-concurrent grunt-nodemon --save-dev
```

Second, load this modules by defining in Gruntfile.js

```
...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'concurrent'
]);
```

Now you are ready to run the task:

```
grunt
```

Bellow you can see entire example of Gruntfile.js with watch, sass and nodemon that I have:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        project: {
            app: ['app'],
            assets: ['assets'],
            scss: ['<%= project.assets %>/sass/css'],
            css: ['<%= project.assets %>/public/css']
        },

        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    compass: false,
                    loadPath: 'bower_components'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= project.css %>/style.css': '<%= project.scss %>/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: '<%= project.scss %>/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: ['sass:dev']
            },
        },

        // watch our node server for changes
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'server.js'
            }
        },

        // run watch and nodemon at the same time
        concurrent: {
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            },
            tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch']
        }   
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'concurrent'
    ]);

};
```